# json.loads string not being read properly from api

Tags: python, json, xml-rpc

I haven't had any luck finding why after running the following code,

```
import xmlrpc.client
import json

from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
api = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("http://user:pass@localhost:8442/")

listAddress = api.listAddresses()

print (listAddress)

jsonAddresses = json.loads(listAddress)
print (jsonAddresses)
```

it tells me that the JSON object must be a string. I added `print (listAddress)` in there to show that it is in fact a string in JSON format And the output prints it out right before telling me that it needs to be a string. Shown here:

```
{'addresses': [{'chan': False, 'address': 'BM-2cXU266jqEXWN9GZ3syVP9dNiWM59z8br8', 'enabled': True, 'stream': 1, 'label': 'unused API address'}, {'chan': False, 'address': 'BM-NB21wfaCzZvmX7BFrat1zSocRuYCMVvQ', 'enabled': True, 'stream': 1, 'label': 'unused API address'}]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/otsudo/Code/part_manager-master/help.py", line 13, in <module>
    jsonAddresses = json.loads(listAddress)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

I have to be missing something here. I appreciate all help.

Comment: `listAddress ` is `dict`, `json.dumps(listAddress)` is string.

Comment: @Otsubosan Do you know the type of listAddress? json.loads only takes string as argument.

Comment: I tried directly accessing `https://demotivation-quotes-api.herokuapp.com/graphql` myself, it appears that this endpoint is NOT a RESTful API interface at all...Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @rubys thank you! That makes more sense. I'm fairly new to using json so I'm guessing this was something obvious that I missed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see documentation for api.listAddresses() but if you wrap a type around listAddress

```
type(listAddress)
```

you will see it already turns it into a python dictionary for you.

So you don't need to load data using the json library.